# How to make field fillable only for admin

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model 'user'. Also I have $fillable fields including 'role' (user or admin) field. I have an 'update' method to edit user's data. Every user may edit only own profile (except admin who may edit all profiles). How can I disallow to edit 'role' to users and allow updating only for admin?

Comment: Your `$user` is `belongsTo()` to `$admin` something like that relationship you need.

Comment: User is model, and 'admin' is just role of user. I have one table for all users. Do you mean I need to create some abstract class something like 'Actor' that will be implemented by 2 different models 'User' and 'Admin' with global scopes 'role'? Is there more simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check role when you want to edit something.
Use relationship is a Example.